Pod install fails with ruby errors
I am trying to add a pod to a new project and it doesn't seem to be working.
Here's what I get: https://pastebin.com/zi55jiUZ
Sorry for the pastebin but it I cannot post if it's too much code (go figure).
If it helps, here's the podfile:
platform :ios, '14.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'CalendarTest' do

  pod 'FSCalendar'

end

Unfortunately, I couldn't find much to help me solve this.
I know it's not much but any ideas?

Finally found a way to fix this:
sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
pod repo update
pod install

Hope this helps someone.
